Can Azure Storage Blob Data Owner access encrypted files using Customer Managed Keys?
We are going to use Customer Managed Keys to encrypt blob file at rest and this blob file contains sensitive data. So, here Blob Data Owner can read this blob file in plain text ?

Decryption happens transparently for anyone who have read permission on the blob.

But my key will be stored in Az Keyvault then how user who has permission on blob can read ?
